# how to past object as child to script tag in react

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

i want to insert one html widget to my react app.
On their site it looks like this

```
<script>{"fieldOne":"value"}</script>
```

and widget works if i past this straight to html.

But when i try to do it in react app it tells me: `Parsing error: Unexpected token, expected "}"`

Answer (score 0):

In JSX, `{` and `}` have a special meaning (wrapping JavaScript inside of the HTML/XML) so you need to have two `{` and two `}` to be able to have that:

```
<script>{{"fieldOne":"value"}}</script>
```